# Measuring magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, instrument

I have been working on developing apparatus for measuring the intensity of magnetic field in Physics experiments for the undergrad lab. Some solutions use miniature hall effect ICs to measure the magnetic fields. However I have doubts that most of the ICs are not designed to be precise. At least the ones we received as a part of a equipment for the lab are known to be imprecise. So my question is: Are there any IC's designed for precision measurement of magnetic fields?

I have recently arranged this model SS59E (picture attached) to be tested. Does anyone know if it designed for precision? [image]

Edit: SS59ET: Range of probe is +-1000 Gauss,  1.4mV/Gauss, linearity -0.7% (of rng), drift <0.2%/C  Earth ... 0.2-0.6 Gauss

Comment: You should define your case first. 1/ What fields do you measure? Earth or e.g. dipole magnet?  2/ Once you know your range - you define your precision - what changes do you need to be able to detect?

Comment: I added some datasheet info- the probe is too big range for Earth, too small for magnetooptics. For magnetooptics, you usually need something more expensive (~10kE) for the precision.

Comment: We use to measure the magnetic field is solenoids used in different experiments. For example the measurement of field in an e/m experiment or a magnetic moment experiment. The field strength do not exceed 1.5 T.

Comment: Then, clearly, you may measure stability from far away, but not the full mg field.

Comment: The problem that I face is that the intensity of the magnetic field is incorrect and, ultimately, that gives incorrect value of the whatever quantity we try to measure. I also found out from my own search that these sensors are better for sensing if a magnetic field is around but not really that good if you want to know the actual strength of the magnetic field.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I tried to formulate all this in one response.

Comment: This is an engineering design question, not a conceptual physics  or physics equipment operational use question.

Comment: Correct. I looked up for a more appropriate Stack Exchange forum to put this but could not find one. Sorry if it does not belong here.

Comment: Have you considered asking the manufacturer such questions?

Answer (score 1):

Hall effect devices are not accurate magnetic field sensors. Main sources of inaccuracy are the high zero-field offset, the temperature coefficient of offset and sensitivity, and the long-term instability. Though there are techniques to mitigate these problems, the accuracy remains poor. Hall effect sensors are thus mainly employed in industrial applications as proximity sensors.

Solid-state sensors with improved performances are the magnetoresistive ones, which are available by several manufacturers (e.g., Honeywell).

For better accuracy, however, one should employ more complex devices like inductive magnetometers (for AC magnetic fields), nuclear magnetic resonance magnetometers, and optically-pumped magnetometers.

Comment: So what makes the magnetoresistive sensors more accurate than the hall effect sensors.

Comment: I mean the temperature effects should also effect the resistance of the sensor just like the hall effect sensor.

Comment: @Shaz Hall effect and magnetoresistive sensors are based on completely different effects, and different are the sensitivity to magnetic field and the sources of errors and temperature sensitivity. If you want to ask about this dependence, it would be better done in another question, because it's a different topic altogether.

Comment: Question created.